# Webapp server data storage: Memory vs database

Tags: database, performance, go, memory, websocket

We are making a web application in Go with a MySQL database. Our users are allowed to only have one active client at a time. Much like Spotify allows you to only listen to music on one device at a time. To do this I made a map with as key the user ids and a reference to their active websocket connection as a value. Based on the websocket id that the client has to send in the header of the request we can identify weather the request comes from their active session.

My question is if it's a good practice to store data (in this case the map with the user ids and websockets) in a global space or is it better to store it in the database.

We don't expect to reach over 10000 simultaneously active clients. Average is probably gonna be around 1000.

Comment: If you will use at most one server to terminate the websocket connections, than it an in memory map is sufficient to record which connection is active for s given user.  If you plan to use more than one server, than more info is needed for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only run one instance of the websocket server storing it in memory should be sufficient. Because if it for some reason goes down/restarts then all the connections will be lost and all the clients will have to create them again (and hence the list of connection will once again be populated by all the clients who want to use the service).

However, if you plan on scaling it horizontally so you have multiple websocket services behind a load balancer, then the connections may need to be stored in a database of some sort. And not because it necessarily needs to be more persistant but because you need to be able to check the request against all the services connections.

It is also possible to have a separate service which handles the incoming request and asks all the websocket services if any of them have the connection specified in the request. This could be done if you add a pub/sub queue and every websocket service subscribes to channels for all its websocket ids and the service that receives the request then publishes the websocket id, and the websocket services can then send back replies on a separate channel if they have that connection. You must decide how to handle if no one is responding (no websocket service has the websocket id). Either the channel does not exist, or you expect the answer within a specific time. Or you could publish the question on a general topic and expect all the websocket services to reply (yes or no).

And regarding whether you need to scale it I guess depends mostly on the underlying server you're running the service on. If I understand it correctly the websocket service will basically not do anything except from keeping track of its connections (you should add some ping pong to discover if connections are lost). Then your limitation should mainly be on how many file descriptors your system can handle at once. If that limit is much larger than your expected maximum number of users, then running only one server and storing everything in memory might be an OK solution!

Finally, if you're in the business of having a websocket open for all users, why not do all the "other" communication over that websocket connection instead of having them send HTTP requests with their websocket id? Perhaps HTTP fits better for your use case but could be something to think about :)